# Getting Evaluated at values on large brackets

Tags: math-mode

For the square brackets in both examples.

I would like to make this

```
$$ \quad \left[ 1+\left( { \frac { 1 }{ 140 } u }^{ 14 } \right)  \right] $$
```

to look like this the values `0` and `1` in this (on the square brackets.)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX! [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) as you may have package which change certain behaviour.  Also, please include the output that you currently obtain.

Comment: Sorry how how should I post my code?

Comment: If you follow [this link](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), it will have nice instructions detailing how to make a good MWE.  Basically, just have `\documentclass` and only the packages in the preamble that are directly relevant to this.  Then you should have `\begin{document}` followed by the code snippet you have above and finally finish it with `\end{document}`.  The idea is that people can come in and copy/paste the code you provide so that we don't have to guess what you might've done which will ultimately help you get an answer :)

Comment: Please read [Why is `\[` … `\]` preferable to `$$`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5764)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the regular super-/subscript notation for setting "ranges" to brackets:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  x &= \biggl[ \frac{t^3}{6} - \frac{t^2}{2} - 6t \biggr]^4_1 \\
  x &= \left[ \frac{t^3}{6} - \frac{t^2}{2} - 6t \right]^4_1
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```